# pixel to pixel with the trajectory of monocular visual odometry

Tags: opencv, image-processing, slam, video-tracking, visual-odometry

i have a trajectory computeted with a monocular visual odometry algorithm (scale is not known). In my first image I marked the middle of an object P(x,y). Is it possible to project the middle of the object (the Pixel P(x,y)) into the other frames by using the trajectory with unknown scale?

with known scale I could used the opencv function "cv2.projectPoints", but is it possible without scale?

-depth1-3 is unkown

-P1(x1,y1) is known

-trajectory is known (without scale)

-P2 and P3 is the result i would like to get

[image]

Comment: can you rephrase that and clarify please. prefer to use pictures if possible to illustrate your point.

Comment: sry for the delay, I updated the question. Hopefully it is now easyer to understand.

Comment: the general problem is called "structure from motion". you want to determine the 3d point that is represented by 2d points in multiple views. you need the 3d point if you want to map it back into any view. a single view, with no depth information, can't give you a point in 3d, it can only give you a ray along which the 3d point could lie. multiple views give multiple rays, and intersecting them gives you the point in 3d. stereo vision the simplest case. please dig into the available literature on SfM, which is vast. book recommendation: multi view geometry by hartley and zisserman.

Comment: " you want to determine the 3d point that is represented by 2d points in multiple views", not necessarily, it would only simplify the matter.  I would prefer not to need "real" 3D points for this. For example, if you look at a mono-SLAM method, it calculates a feature point cloud that is not defined in its scaling. But I can assign each of these points to a pixel. My hope is that I can do this with other points/pixel as well (in a magical way ;) ).

Comment: not everything is possible by wishing it. please read about the math involved.